# Building a JSON string with multiple level arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need this result in PHP:

```
$pass->setJSON('{
          "formatVersion" : 1,
          "description" : "title",
          "coupon" : {
            "primaryFields" : [
              {
                "key" : "offer",
                "label" : "title",
                "value" : "50%"
              }
            ],
          }           
        }');
```

I try to build this with arrays:

```
$jsonpost = array();
$jsonpost['formatVersion'] = '1';
$jsonpost['description'] = "test";
```

And then convert with JSON_ENCODE:

```
$json = json_encode($jsonpost);
$pass->setJSON($json);
```

How do I set the multi level array (coupons) in PHP?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
$jsonpost['coupon']['primaryFields'][] = [
'key' => 'offer',
'label' => 'title',
'value' => '50%',
];
```

Or if you use PHP < 5.4 you should use syntax:

```
$jsonpost['coupon']['primaryFields'][] = array(
   'key' => 'offer',
   'label' => 'title',
   'value' => '50%',
);
```

This is because `primaryFields` in your Json needs to be an array so extra `[]` as added at the end, and `primaryFields` is property for `coupon` object

Comment: no explanation, OP don't know why he has to write it like this!

Answer (score 0):

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: look at my edited answer, you probably use PHP < 5.4